# Update TableView in a view controller with updated data

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am fetching some data from the WCF webservice in a separate thread after each 30 seconds...
and I want something like that a view controller having table view keeps on getting updated whenever i receive fresh data...how can I achieve that...I tried notification but that requires me to come on that particular view controller....

Any advise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. You need not to be on the controller when you send notification.
2. You can achieve it also using delegates, just called the method of the controller which reload the data of table view when you receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question correctly: You want to get data from a webservice and then update a tableview once you have retrieved the data.

Here's some mockup code:
    wcfWebserviceFetcher.tableViewDelegate = mainTableView;

Now in the wcfWebserviceFetcher:

```
-(void) dataFetchDone {
    if(tableViewDelegate!=nil) {
       tableViewDelegate.data = self.wcfWebserviceDataResult;
       [tableViewDelegate reloadData];
    }
}
```